# failed: semanticexception the current builtin authoization in hive is incomplete and disabled

Tags: hadoop

I start the sentry service(*without kerberos, ad or ldap*), and config hive, impala with sentry.

Then I used beeline to connect hive2(**beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://**),

and ran the command "create role test_role", but it throwed an error.
What could cause it happen?

The following is the log:

```
[root@cdh1 ~]# su - hive -s /bin/bash
[hive@cdh1 ~]$ beeline
Beeline version 0.13.1-cdh5.3.0 by Apache Hive
beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://
scan complete in 3ms
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://
Enter username for jdbc:hive2://: 
Enter password for jdbc:hive2://: 
16/02/19 13:46:20 WARN conf.HiveConf: DEPRECATED: Configuration property hive.metastore.local no longer has any effect. Make sure to provide a valid value for hive.metastore.uris if you are connecting to a remote metastore.
16/02/19 13:46:20 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://cdh1:9083
16/02/19 13:46:20 INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO session.SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
16/02/19 13:46:21 WARN conf.HiveConf: DEPRECATED: Configuration property hive.metastore.local no longer has any effect. Make sure to provide a valid value for hive.metastore.uris if you are connecting to a remote metastore.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.CompositeService: HiveServer2: Background operation thread pool size: 100
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.CompositeService: HiveServer2: Background operation thread wait queue size: 100
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.CompositeService: HiveServer2: Background operation thread keepalive time: 10
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:OperationManager is inited.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:LogManager is inited.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:SessionManager is inited.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:CLIService is inited.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:OperationManager is started.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:LogManager is started.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:SessionManager is started.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:CLIService is started.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO hive.metastore: Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://cdh1:9083
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO hive.metastore: Connected to metastore.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO thrift.ThriftCLIService: Client protocol version: HIVE_CLI_SERVICE_PROTOCOL_V6
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO session.SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
16/02/19 13:46:21 INFO session.SessionState: No Tez session required at this point. hive.execution.engine=mr.
Connected to: Apache Hive (version 0.13.1-cdh5.3.0)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 0.13.1-cdh5.3.0)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
0: jdbc:hive2://> 
0: jdbc:hive2://> create role test_role;
16/02/19 13:46:32 INFO log.LogManager: Operation log size: 131072
16/02/19 13:46:32 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=compile from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/02/19 13:46:32 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=parse from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/02/19 13:46:32 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parsing command: create role test_role
16/02/19 13:46:32 INFO parse.ParseDriver: Parse Completed
16/02/19 13:46:32 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=parse start=1455860792301 end=1455860792688 duration=387 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/02/19 13:46:32 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=semanticAnalyze from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
FAILED: SemanticException The current builtin authorization in Hive is incomplete and disabled.
16/02/19 13:46:32 ERROR ql.Driver: FAILED: SemanticException The current builtin authorization in Hive is incomplete and disabled.
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.SemanticException: The current builtin authorization in Hive is incomplete and disabled.
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.authorization.RestrictedHiveAuthorizationTaskFactoryImpl.raiseAuthError(RestrictedHiveAuthorizationTaskFactoryImpl.java:140)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.authorization.RestrictedHiveAuthorizationTaskFactoryImpl.createCreateRoleTask(RestrictedHiveAuthorizationTaskFactoryImpl.java:47)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.DDLSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeCreateRole(DDLSemanticAnalyzer.java:559)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.DDLSemanticAnalyzer.analyzeInternal(DDLSemanticAnalyzer.java:455)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer.analyze(BaseSemanticAnalyzer.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:437)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:335)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1026)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileAndRespond(Driver.java:1019)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:100)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.run(SQLOperation.java:173)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.runOperationWithLogCapture(HiveSessionImpl.java:715)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:370)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:357)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:237)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:392)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:232)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:736)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:657)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.dispatch(BeeLine.java:910)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.execute(BeeLine.java:772)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:734)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.mainWithInputRedirection(BeeLine.java:469)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.main(BeeLine.java:452)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

16/02/19 13:46:32 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=compile start=1455860792263 end=1455860792747 duration=484 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/02/19 13:46:32 INFO log.PerfLogger: <PERFLOG method=releaseLocks from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/02/19 13:46:32 INFO log.PerfLogger: </PERFLOG method=releaseLocks start=1455860792747 end=1455860792747 duration=0 from=org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver>
16/02/19 13:46:32 WARN thrift.ThriftCLIService: Error executing statement: 
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException The current builtin authorization in Hive is incomplete and disabled.
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.prepare(SQLOperation.java:102)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.run(SQLOperation.java:173)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.runOperationWithLogCapture(HiveSessionImpl.java:715)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementInternal(HiveSessionImpl.java:370)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.executeStatementAsync(HiveSessionImpl.java:357)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.executeStatementAsync(CLIService.java:237)
at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.ExecuteStatement(ThriftCLIService.java:392)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveStatement.execute(HiveStatement.java:232)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:736)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:657)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.dispatch(BeeLine.java:910)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.execute(BeeLine.java:772)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:734)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.mainWithInputRedirection(BeeLine.java:469)
at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.main(BeeLine.java:452)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Error: Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException The current builtin authorization in Hive is incomplete and disabled. (state=42000,code=40000)
```

0: jdbc:hive2://>

Answer (score -1):

"Enter username for jdbc:hive2://:" prompt is empty.
You need to provide the username of the sentry admin, one of the sentry.metastore.service.users values.